# Let $G$ be a biconnected graph, $\{x,y\} \subseteq V(G)$ be a separator. Show that if $e=\{x,y\} \in E(G)$, then $G\backslash e$ is biconnected.

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Let $G$ be a biconnected graph, let $w,z \in V(G)$ and $e=\{x,y\} \in E(G)$.

**Here's my try:**

*It will be shown that*, there are two internally distinct paths joining vertices $w,z$ (so $G\backslash e$ is biconnected).

As $G$ is biconnected, there are two internally distinct paths connecting the vertices $w,z$, let $P,Q$ be those.

**Case $\textbf{1}$:**  $w,z$ belong to different connected components of $G\backslash e$.

It's true that $e \notin E(P)\cup E(Q)$. Indeed, since $P,Q$ are internally distinct,

e $\in E(P)\cup E(Q) \Rightarrow e \in E(P) \veebar e \in E(Q)$  .

Then, removing it would affect only $1$ path, the path to which edge $e$ belonged. Therefore, the vertices would continue to belong to the same connected components, **contradiction**.

We have nothing to prove, since removing $e$ does not affect either of the two internally distinct paths.

**Case $\textbf{2}$:**  $w,z$ belong to the same connected component of $G\backslash e$.

Let $X,Y$ be two connected components of $G\backslash e$.

- If $e \notin E(P)\cup E(Q)$ we have nothing to prove, since, in this case, the two internally distinct $(w,z)$-paths are not affected by the removal of edge $e$.
- If $e \in E(P)\cup E(Q)$ ?

I considered a vertex $u$ in some other connected component of $G\backslash e$, but couldn't find two internally distinct paths joining vertices $w,z$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, at some point you'll have to use the assumption $\{x,y\} \subset V(G)$ is a separator.  Do you have any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Let $X,Y$ be two connected components of $G\backslash\ e, w,z \in V(X)$ and let $u \in V(Y)$. Let $e\notin E(P)$ and $e\in E(Q)$ (it cannot belong to both paths).
We have that in $G$ there exists a $(x,y)$-path, $R$, which passes through $u$ and $x,y\in V(R)$. It holds that $e\notin E(R)$.

So the path $R$ also exists in the graph $G\backslash e$. We then have that the paths:

Comment: \begin{align*}
&P \\
Q|_{[z,x]}\cup &R\cup Q|_{[y,w]}
\end{align*}
are two internally distinct $(z,w)-$paths. Indeed, if they had any point in common, since the points of $P, R$ are in different connected components of $G\backslash e$), $\{x,y\}$ would not be separator.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure why you keep on talking about connected components of $G\setminus e$, which you'd already shown is connected.  it's possible you meant $G \setminus \{x,y\}$ interpreted as a the induced subgraph on the vertex set $V(G) \setminus \{x,y\}$, but then you need to be careful that $\{z,w\} \cap \{x,y\} = \emptyset$.  Once you consider that, the basic structure of your proof is right, but the details are lacking.